# Spring cloud dataflow app http returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am testing scdf with iris PA example which deployed "http | pmml | log" example

But when I post a request to the server, I always got:

```
401 Unauthorized
```

like these:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1484718462061,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path": "/"
}
```

When I added `application.properties` file with this configuration:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

to the folder same with the local server `jar` file, it seemed not working...

I still saw the default password been set in the console:

```
using default security password: ****-****....
```

Then I used the `Basic Auth` with username `user` and password `****-***`

it gave:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1484718712952,
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "path": "/"
}
```

Infos:

```
plateform: docker-toolbox
OS: debian:jessie
SCDF version: 1.1.1.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been addressed in the recent 1.1.2.RELEASE of `http-source` application - more details on where to download the latest bits can be found in [#1130](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1130#issuecomment-273495206).